# How to display images edge-to-edge in ipython notebook?

Tags: html, css, svg, jupyter-notebook

I need to add a graphical letterhead to the top of the first page of my jupyter notebook. 
It runs from the top edge of the paper to the left and right edges for the height of the svg image.

I have tried a markdown cell with:

```
<img style="float: left;" src="page_header.svg" width=740 height=160>
```

This results in the image being padded to fit within the "output cell" area.

I've also tried a code cell (with hidden input):

```
from IPython.core.display import Image, display
display(Image(url="http://localhost:8888/files/page_header.svg", width=740, height=160, unconfined=True))
```

Which results in the image being about the right scale, but contained within a small window with scroll bars again within the output cell area.

Is there any way to have the image placed across the 'paper' such that printing from the browser to a pdf results in the image at the top of the page, and edge to edge, where it belongs?